# Image falls out of box

Tags: css, image, css-float

Hello i'm new to html & css. I started with making a box in wich i would like to display a image at the right side of the box. But for some reason my image ends up under the box. Please help. 
box name = content and i made this in css like this:

```
#content{
 margin: 30px 0;
 background: white;
 padding: 20px;
 clear: both;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}
```

css for the image:

```
#img{
 float:right;
 padding: 20px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

here is the html code:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Kleding</h2>
    <div id="navbanner">
    <div id="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Babynav">Baby</a></li>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Peuternav">Peuter</a></li>
            <li><a href="../html/kleding.html"id="Kleuternav">Kleuter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="img">
      <img src="../images/winkelwagen.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: Try 'float:left' for your box, or 'display:block' on both. its always a good idea to show your HTML, preferably a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bit of messup with the alignment of the elements.

To minimize this, use:

```
img { // for the image not the div..
 max-width: 100px;
}
```

You can alter the `100px` depending on the width provided there. This way, the width of the image will be lessen down to fit it to the place.

**The error in your code:**

The issue was with the height of the element. The list you were creating had its own margins and paddings too. Which was causing the image to move outside the box.

**Solution:**

Due to this reason, I applied `height` to `content` and got the image inside the box. Because now the div had some more height to cover the image inside it. But still the `ul` has its own margins and padding. To completely remove the issue. Use

```
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for this, have a look!

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/AjvuE/

Comment: If i use max-width: 500px; the image moves away from or to the border of my browserscreen.

Comment: Wait I hve created a fiddle

Comment: have a look now.. I have explained the issue and added a fiddle too :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify `height` for `content`:

```
#content{
margin: 30px 0;
background: white;
padding: 20px;
clear: both;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Changing the heigt seems to work. Only a height: auto doens't for some reason.

Comment: It works..If it doesn't then add `overflow:hidden` on content. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem..:)

Answer (score 0):

1. define `height` and `width` for `#content`
2. put the `h2` into the `#navbanner` div
3. float `#navbanner` to left

see this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/udOcab/1/

(NOTE: I changed the image to the google logo so you could actually view the image for the example. Also I added a background to the divs so you could see where they are positioned.)